# Date iteration with Rcpp loop

Tags: r, loops, rcpp

For fastening purpose, i'm trying to convert a simple 'for loop' in R into a Rcpp one.

I have a date vector named "date_vector" which is composed by X identical dates.
For each iteration of i, I add 1 minutes to the date_vector value.
The R 'for loop' (see below) works properly, but it is too slow for my very large dataset (2 years ~ 1million of rows).

I've read that Rccp could be a solution to speed up the loop.
However, I'm a 'Rcpp' noob and I'm struggling to convert my loop.

Can someone help me and explain me the solution ? Thank you very much!
Best wishes for 2023.

The orignial R Loop :

```
for(i in 2:nrow(klines)){
  
  date_vector[i] <- date_vector[i-1]+minutes(1)
  
}
```

My Rcpp loop attempt:

```
cpp_update_date_vector <- cppFunction('DateVector fonction_test(DateVector zz),
  
  int n = zz.size();
  DateVector = date_vector;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
    date_vector[i] = date_vector[i-1] + 60; 
  
  }
')
```

Comment: You don't need a loop here. Just use `date_vector[1] + lubridate::minutes(seq(nrow(klines)) - 1)`. This is already vectorized at the C level, so there will be little to no benefit reinventing the wheel in Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can likely achieve your goal without a loop at all. It sounds like you’re trying to change a vector of identical datetimes to a sequence one minute apart, right? If so, you could do:

```
library(lubridate) 

date_vector <- rep(ymd_hms("2020-01-01 12:00:00"), 10)

date_vector + minutes(seq_along(date_vector) - 1)
```

```
 [1] "2020-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-01 12:01:00 UTC"
 [3] "2020-01-01 12:02:00 UTC" "2020-01-01 12:03:00 UTC"
 [5] "2020-01-01 12:04:00 UTC" "2020-01-01 12:05:00 UTC"
 [7] "2020-01-01 12:06:00 UTC" "2020-01-01 12:07:00 UTC"
 [9] "2020-01-01 12:08:00 UTC" "2020-01-01 12:09:00 UTC"
```

Comment: How about the plain old base R equivalent `seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01 12:00:00"), by = "1 min", length = 10)`

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your solution is short and works well. My mind was stuck in 'for loops' and i didnt think out of the box.

Comment: For completeness you also do not need `lubdridate`.  You can do all this in base R. And if you have a need for speed `data.table` _excels_ at these types of operations as well as at grouping, summaries, transformations, ...

Comment: @Beeflight31 that’s very common if you’re coming to R from another language where loops often are a good solution. Though loops have their place in R, in most cases there’s a better vectorized solution.

Comment: @zephryl also note that the lubridate version is hundreds of times slower than either the base R version or Rcpp version, though of course still much faster than the R loop.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here is how you would write the code in Rcpp:

```r
cpp_update_date_vector <- Rcpp::cppFunction('
DatetimeVector fonction_test(DatetimeVector zz) {
    for (int i = 1; i < zz.size(); i++) {
      zz[i] = zz[i-1] + 60; 
    }
  return zz;
}
')
```

But it is no faster then base R's `seq` function, which can easily create a sequence of date-times 1 minute apart. Here is a comparison of the two methods on a 1,000,000-length date-time vector. Note that they are both comparable, and both considerably faster than using `lubridate`.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lubridate = big_vec + lubridate::minutes(seq_along(big_vec) - 1),
  Rcpp = cpp_update_date_vector(big_vec),
  base_R = seq(big_vec[1], by = "1 min", length = 1000000)
)

#> Unit: milliseconds
#> expr           min       lq    mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#> lubridate 1168.921 1203.845 1318.950 1215.465 1570.376 1691.765   100   b
#>      Rcpp    3.733    3.770    8.742    3.799    3.909  467.236   100  a 
#>    base_R    2.172    2.338    3.167    2.407    2.484   40.222   100  a
```

Comment: That's a little apples-vs-oranges.  Make the fight 'loop vs loop' and 'vectorised vs vectorised' without crossing it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm not sure what you mean. Both versions here are compiled-code loops. Apples all round!, Clearly either will be much faster than a base R loop. I might add the lubridate option to the benchmark out of curiosity.

Comment: You can call Rcpp sugar functions for `seq` and alike to have an Rcpp-non-explicit-loop version (that will unroll internally faster than the naive common one you have).  So to be plain, it is not appropriate to compare an _explicit_ loop with an _implicit_ one. If I ran this comparison, I would try to compare to explicit approaches, and then do another on two implicit ones.  Seems more focussed to me.  Anyway....

Comment: Thank you Allan for the details. I appreciate the rcpp explanation (im trying to learn how to rcpp loops because i'm working on big back-test problems).